# Getting Failed to create Jar file /.gradle/caches/jars-8/3ad27c41282f0b1cf50a8248be075dfa/aspectjtools-1.8.13.jar

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

**Failed to create Jar file /.gradle/caches/jars-8/3ad27c41282f0b1cf50a8248be075dfa/aspectjtools-1.8.13.jar.**

Using mac m1 pro and android studio

Android Studio Bumblebee | 2021.1.1 Beta 4
Build #AI-211.7628.21.2111.7905991, built on November 11, 2021
Runtime version: 11.0.11+0-b60-7772763 aarch64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
macOS 12.0.1
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 1280M
Cores: 10
Registry: external.system.auto.import.disabled=true

Any help appriciated.

Comment: Hi! Did you manage to solve the problem? I've been racking my brains over this for days.